# ggplot graph x axis width limits R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame` that I plot using `ggplot2`.

The problem is that when the picture actually produced in R markdown/R Studio Plots tab I get it with the standard width. 
I want to increase the width of the x-axis, to expand it.

I have tried using the limits attribute of `scale_x_continues` without luck.

```
    ggplot(wo_inf, aes(Thresh, value, col = factor(key))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Error Indicator") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(wo_inf$Thresh, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                        max(wo_inf$Thresh, na.rm = TRUE), by = 0.05),2), limits = c(0, 5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("False Acceptance and False Rejection Rates vs. Risk Score Threshold")
```

My Thresh column is between 0 to 5.

Please guide what parameter should I change while producing the `ggplot` to change the width.

P.S I HAVE CHECKED OTHER ANSWERS HERE AND ON GOOGLE, ALMOST ALL OF THEM USING PNG FUNCTION AND R MARKDOWN PARAMETER WITHIN {}, I WANT TO BE ABLE TO CONFIGURE IT WHILE PRODUCING THE PLOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to increase the plot's width, you can add a value for **fig.width** in your RMarkdown as below:

````
```{r fig.width=10}
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point() 
```
````

But, if are trying to change the limits of your x axis, you can add you values (0, 5) in the **xlim()** as follows:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + 
xlim(0, 5)
```